# What is the ObjectRepository in doctrine and what is his role

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

In Doctrine there is an interface `Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectRepository` .
Can someone explain the role and what are the uses of this interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's not a `Class`, it's an `Interface`. It's part of the Doctrine Common library

It's implemented the Doctrine ORM library (`Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository`) and by the Doctrine MongoDB Object Document Mapper (`Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentRepository`).

If you don't want to use Doctrine ORM or MongoDB and write your own ObjectRepository instead, you should implement the interface.

The most common way to write your own EntityRepository (with Doctrine ORM) is to extend `Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository`.

Comment: I changed class by interface in my question. Thanks